# character becomes "?" in varchar field SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar

I want to insert a string value in a field of my SQL Server DB. Sometimes, some values are replaced to "?" . An example:

```
Update myTable set varchar_field = '2 ⅞ RP' where id = 1;
```

The value that is inserted in the database is: `2 ? RP`.

Is there any way to insert the value ⅞ Without it becoming "?"?

At other times, the value is inserted correctly, for example, the value "2 ¾ FP" is inserted correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: You should use `NVARCHAR` column type.

Comment: clearly a `collation` issue. Check and verify the same.